# how to prevent to stop p:poll after navigating to another page in browser

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:poll` in my page. When the page is loaded in browser poll should be stat after click on begin button to show run a counter. My problem starts when the user navigate to another page, by click on 'Go to page One'. Because poll time tick is stopped after navigating. when you come back you should click again on begin button to restart counter. Please help me, how to prevent to stop the poll after navigating to another page. I want `p:poll` continue under any circumstances. I am using primefaces and Apache myfaces 2-2-10. This is a sample that have to page. In page one there are two button. after clicking on Begin button counter starts to show numbers. and button 'Go to Page One' change the page to one.xhtml. in page one after clicking on 'Go to index Page' change the page to index.xhtml page. After this going in and out you will see the counter is stoped. when you click again on 'Begin' button counter start to show enumerate again. My gole is when the user navigate on each page, counter continue and not stop. Thank you for your response.

This Index.xhtml page:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form id="mainForm">

        <p:panelGrid id="pnl" columns="3" rendered="true" columnClasses="ui-column-p-2">

            <p:outputLabel id="lblMessage" value="#{test.count}"/>
            <p:commandButton id="btnStart" value="Begin" onclick="PF('poll').start();"/>
            <p:commandButton id="btnTest" actionListener="#{test.gotoOne}" value="Go To Page One"/>

        </p:panelGrid>

        <p:poll id="poll"  autoStart="false" listener="#{test.counter}"
                update="mainForm:lblMessage" widgetVar="poll"/>
    </h:form>

</h:body>

</html>
```

And this is one.xhtml page:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton id="pn" actionListener="#{test.gotoIndex}" value="Go To Page Index"/>
    </h:form>

</h:body>

</html>
```

At last this is my bean, that generate the numbers:

```
package bean;


import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import java.io.IOException;

@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class Test {

    private int count;

    public void counter() {
        count++;
        System.out.println("count = " + count);
    }

    public void gotoIndex() {
        try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("index.xhtml");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void gotoOne() {
        try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("one.xhtml");
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('poll').start();");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put it in every page? Or In the main template. No other option (unless using the 'old' html <frame> construction). Better to not use poll but push, but you still have to put it in every page or in the template.

Comment: It kind of is identical to stating: When a page is loaded, I show an logo/company/banner image, but when the use navigates away, I still want it to be displayed. And you do not know what page the user navigates to. Solution: display it in every page. Better solution: put it in a template.

Comment: Thank you for response. but your suggestion is not practical. I have a line chart component in this page. In the backend a method runs every second to generate new point to show in the line chart graph. this method runs by p:poll that starts a thread. when the user navigate to another page p:poll thread stops. I need it continue the time tick for users who are still on this page.

Comment: Then your question was badly formulated. You effectively have a p:poll for each user that is on a page that access the same data generated by one thread. But if one user navigates away, the thread stops and all **other** users do not see updates any more. Is that the right description? Then just make sure the thread is not stopped... Show a [mcve]

Comment: Your right. My revision question is ready. And about your description: Yes is true except that as I shown in the code, I have only one p:poll for all users. because the scope of the relevant bean adjusted on 'ApplicationScoped'. so this bean should be share for all users. I appreciate you so much to spend time to answer. I am waiting if you suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the solution. it's using of time scheduler instead of p:poll. I can use Quartz Time scheduler, Spring Framework Time Scheduler or EJB Time Scheduler.

Comment: Sorry, but this can'tbe an answer. `p:poll` is a (maiinly client-side) ui component and the ejb scheduler a server-side component.

Comment: As a matter of fact my mistake was, using a client side thread. like p:poll. When I am using a server side time scheduler, there is no dependency to any client. So no client side events, can stop my timer. My Tools and frameworks are: WildFly 10.1.0, Relevant EJB and Mojarra, Primefaces 6.1.